# WSO2 ESB Edit /Modified registry values on console, not picked up by proxy/inbound-endpoint

Tags: wso2, registry, wso2-esb

Ok, I have some paramters defined in registry of management console :

```
<parameter key="conf:/repository/FilePattern" name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern"/>
```

I initially defined a value in console and after deploying a CAR file, it worked.

When I modify the registry parameter in console with new value, it is not picked by my deployment CAR.

> Do I need to restart the EI611 server
>   with `integrator.bat --run` everytime, I change the value of parameter defined in the registry?

EI611 is running locally on my laptop with default setup, OOTB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no replies from WSO2, I believe that changing parameters, `enableCache or DefaultcacheTimeout` in

1. registry.xml
2. carbon.xml

   respectively, did not help. Restarting the server, was the only option.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably due to the registry cache. As a workaround, you can disable registry caching in `<ESB_HOME>/repository/conf/registry.xml` (or `<EI_HOME>/conf/registry.xml`), while you're in the development phase. Make sure to have caching enabled in production though.

```
<enableCache>false</enableCache>
```

Comment: Thanks, I disabled the registry caching  in the file,  C:\wso2ei-6.1.1\conf\registry.xml, as follows : 
    <currentDBConfig>wso2registry</currentDBConfig>
    <readOnly>false</readOnly>
    <enableCache>false</enableCache>
    <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>

    <dbConfig name="wso2registry">
        <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dataSource>
    </dbConfig>  There was no effect to it, I tested by changing the values of the parameter, my deployment applciation(inbound endpoint VFS) did not receive the latest value. I had to restart the EI611 again to effect it. Any other settings?

Comment: Can you try changing `<DefaultCacheTimeout>` to `1 minute` in `<EI_HOME>/conf/carbon.xml`? Check how long it takes to reflect the change.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I changed the DefaultCacheTimeout to 1 and it did not work. I waited 1 minute, then waited 15 minutes, still there was no change. I mean , the new value of the registry parameter was not picked by my Deployment Application.  bouncing the server (restart) was the only option. Appreciate if you/WSO2 can confirm, this is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

With no replies from WSO2, I conclude that registry values change only, after restarting server. changing

```
enableCache
```

parameter to

> false/true

in registry.xml did not help.